# How to combine three arrays with [0] as key into one

Tags: php, arrays

How can i turn this array:

```
Array ( [0] => 80 ) Array ( [0] => 20 ) Array ( [0] => 90 )
```

Into such array:

```
Array (
[0] => 80,
[1] => 20,
[2] => 90
);
```

Code:

```
$percentage_result = $percentage_query->result_array(); //output below:
```

Output:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 62
            [list_id] => 55
            [start_date] => 1459987200
            [end_date] => 1459987200
            [percentage] => 80
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 64
            [list_id] => 55
            [start_date] => 1459814400
            [end_date] => 1459814400
            [percentage] => 20
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 63
            [list_id] => 55
            [start_date] => 1459900800
            [end_date] => 1459900800
            [percentage] => 90
        )
```

I want to save all of the [percentage] and get the highest one.

Doing this:

```
                $null = array();
                foreach ($percentage_result as $ptime) {            

                //Days between start date and end date -> seasonal price
                $start_time = $ptime['start_date'];
                $end_time = $ptime['end_date'];

                $percentage_sm = explode(',', $ptime['percentage']);


                $mrg = array_merge($null, $percentage_sm);

                print_r($mrg);
```

$msg shows me:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => 80
)
Array
(
    [0] => 20
)
Array
(
    [0] => 90
)
```

Comment: [array_merge()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) perhaps.... try looking at the PHP docs.... they can be very helpful

Comment: @SunilPachlangia it doesn't work.

Comment: @IlanHasanov show your code how you have tried

Comment: Pls show the code that does not work

Comment: If you've tried something and it didn't work, then tell us what you tried, and what didn't work

Comment: @MarkBaker Added the piece of code.

Comment: Now you have totally change the question

Comment: @IlanHasanov see answer

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in very simple way like this

```
$percentage_sm = array(); //define blank array
foreach ($percentage_result as $ptime) {            

    //Days between start date and end date -> seasonal price
    $start_time = $ptime['start_date'];
    $end_time = $ptime['end_date'];

    $percentage_sm[] = $ptime['percentage'];  //assign every value to array
}

print_r($percentage_sm);
```

Comment: It seems to be working, however if i print_r outside the foreach it doesn't. what is the reason?

Comment: Have you define array $percentage_sm = array(); before foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_merge()`

```
$result = array_merge($arr1, $arr2, $arr3);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the highest percentage value from your $percentage_result array, then the easiest way to do it is

```
$maxPercentage = max(array_column($percentage_result, 'percentage'));
```

rather than trying to do something weird with array_merge

(PHP >= 5.5.0)

If you're running a lower version of PHP, then you can do something similar with

```
$maxPercentage = max(
    array_map(
        $percentage_result, 
            function ($value) { return $value['percentage']; }
    )
);
```